# Easy way to remove what's NOT in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there an easy way to get the opposite of a regex or do I need to build a new regex that produces the opposite of what I have?

For example, I use this regex to make sure I'm getting proper currency values -- without $ sign.

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$/
```

I want to now remove everything that falls outside this pattern. For example, if user enters letters or tries to enter two periods e.g. 7.50.6, I want to remove undesired characters. How do I do that?

Comment: how are you using the regex?

Comment: I currently use it to test i.e. myValue.test(myRegex); But now in my React app, I want to completely prevent undesired values from being entered by the user.

Comment: Maybe try `value = value.match(/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?/)[0]`? It may be what you're after

Comment: I think you're suggesting to use match instead of test, correct? I tried that but it didn't work.  Or am I not following you?

Comment: I'm not sure arbitrarily removing things is a good plan here. Europeans use `.` as a thousands separator. Displaying an error is better than silently mangling input and putting in bad data.

Comment: It really is not silent at all. What the user is typing simply does not show up in the input box if it's invalid. This is a common approach in React -- called Controlled Components: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going at this in the wrong way. First of all, trying to hide input error in such a way is a bad idea. If a user has to type a number and they put an extra dot, what tells you which is the good part and which is the bad? You're better off telling the user there's something wrong with their input.

But typically, you use a regex by specifying what it has to look like AND what are the significant portions you want to keep using capture groups.

This is a capture group: `([a-z0-9])@example.com`; this is a non-capture group: `(?:hello|hi)`.

In case of a phone number, all that matters are the digits, so you can capture them and accept multiple forms of in-between characters. Here's a simple one for a postal code:

```
([A-Z][0-9][A-Z]) ?([0-9][A-Z][0-9])
```

Then all you have to do is combine the captured groups. If present, the space won't be captured.

Find more examples on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Examples).

Comment: Despite your suggestions, it still doesn't answer how to potentially reverse a regex

Comment: I'm NOT trying to hide anything. I'm removing them. For example, what's the point in allowing the user to type letters in a phone number then telling him to fix it. Because React is all about managing the state, I can detect that the user has entered letters and simply NOT put them in my state. By doing this, I can have a tightly managed input field.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't answer how to invert a regex. I highly doubt it's something worth trying - I see this as the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).